# Makefile: ignore prerequisite if it does not exist

Tags: makefile

I have a datafile that depends on other datafiles, but the generating script ignores if they are missing. The script automatically creates the makefile, including the ones that do not exist - that in the case they get created, the depending file is recreated.

```
data: infile1.raw infile2.raw
      touch $@
infile1.raw:
infile2.raw:
```

Adding empty rules avoids an error, but triggers an unwanted recreation.

Implicit rules work sometimes, but not reliable - `%.raw:` causes make to complain that there is no rule to make the `infile1.raw` targets. Explicitly stating that it does not need to be build with `%.raw:;` removes the error, but causes again a rebuild. I would hope to avoid wildcards such as

```
data: $(wildcard infile*.raw)
```

as it very hard to automate this in such a way that not far to many files are matched.

Is there a way to achieve that make ignores missing dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @user657267's answer, it seems you can simply use `wildcard` with a fixed file name:

```
data: $(wildcard infile1.raw) $(wildcard infile2.raw)
    touch $@
```

Note that this will not detect the case where an input file was deleted (e.g. if you concatenate all input files, deleting one will **not** cause the target to be rebuilt).

Answer (score 2):

If `wildcard` alone is giving you too many spurious matches, use `wildcard` with a whitelist

```
whitelist := infile1.raw infile2.raw

data: $(filter $(whitelist),$(wildcard infile*.raw))
```